# Pointer receiver confusion

Tags: go

I'm confused about the behaviour of the following code. [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/NOyjfYPuik)

```
var foo json.RawMessage
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{ "zoo": 123 }`), &foo)

enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)

// Works as expected
_ = enc.Encode(struct{ Foo *json.RawMessage }{&foo})

// MarshalJSON has a pointer reciever, so it doesn't get invoked here
_ = enc.Encode(struct{ Foo json.RawMessage }{foo})

// How is MarshalJSON being invoked if .Foo is not a pointer?
_ = enc.Encode(&struct{ Foo json.RawMessage }{foo})
```

Output:

```
{"Foo":{"zoo":123}}
{"Foo":"eyAiem9vIjogMTIzIH0="}
{"Foo":{"zoo":123}}
```

I don't understand why the third call to `json.Encoder.Encode` is able to access `json.RawMessage.MarshalJSON` even though it's not a pointer.

Comment: The third call doesn't call MarshalJSON(), it uses reflect to guess the type and encode as best is possible. Take a look at json.(*Encode).Encode() function: http://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=4283:4330#L173

Comment: @divan how come that doesn't happen in the second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method on any [addressable value](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), Go will automatically reference the value to call methods with a pointer receiver.

```
type Foo struct{}
func (f *Foo) Call() {}

// f isn't a pointer, but is addressable
f := Foo{}
f.Call()
```

Also, if a non-pointer value is in an addressable struct, it can also be reference for methods requiring a pointer receiver.

```
type Bar struct {
    Foo Foo
}

// b is addressable, therefor so is b.Foo
b := Bar{
    Foo: f,
}
b.Foo.Call()
```

Your last example uses the address of the outer struct to get the address of the Foo field, and call `MarshalJSON`.

Comment: In the second example, the struct literal is being created on the stack, and is then copied into `Encode`s stack frame. Why is it not considered "addressable"? Values on the stack are addressable.

Comment: @iliacholy: whether it's on the stack or not is irrelevant to the specification of addressability, but in the second example a _copy_ of the struct literal is allocated in the `interface{}` argument in the stack. A value in an interface is not addressable.